# Proxmox VE: add a LVM storage on top of iSCSI: how to find "base" value for pvesm

Tags: lvm, iscsi, proxmox, open-iscsi

I'm using Proxmox VE platform, version 6 or 7, and I'm currently documenting the initial setup with the idea of automating it later.
So I'm looking for all command line commands to do all that I must do on the web UI.

My problem is in the storage configuration step: I try to configure an LVM volume on top of an iSCSI LUN.

If I do this setup with the web UI, the `/etc/pve/storage.cfg` looks like

```
iscsi: <ID1>
    portal <portal>
    target <target>
    content none

lvm: <ID2>
    vgname <vgname>
    base <ID SCSI>
    content rootdir,images
    shared 1
```

I can use the `pvesm` utility to do it with the following commands

```
pvesm add iscsi <ID> --portal <SERVER> --target <TARGET> --content none

pvesm add lvm <ID> --vgname <vgname> --base <ID SCSI>
```

The problem is I don't know how to find this **ID SCSI**, neither using any PVE or open-iscsi tool.

*ps: the "ID SCSI" looks like `<ID1>:0.0.0.scsi-<1234000afbc....>`*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I found the answer by myself just half an hour after asking the question... well... that happens...

`pvesm list <ID>` returns this `ID SCSI` which I needs to configure/create the LVM VG

```
# pvesm list <ID1>
Volid                                                               Format  Type                Size VMID
<ID SCSI> raw     images    <number>
# pvesm add lvm <ID2> --vgname <vgname> --base <ID SCSI>
  Physical volume "/dev/disk/by-id/<ID SCSI>" successfully created.
  Volume group "<vgname>" successfully created
```